# How do you cite articles from a "database?"

Tags: citations

Cochrane reviews are great to cite in academic publications due to their systematic nature but I have no idea how to cite them in APA style because there's no obvious volume or issue to use in the citation. Here's a reference I've already tried, albeit awaiting on the volume and issuing numbers I'm meant to give.

```
Linde K., Berner M. M., Kriston L. (2008). St John's wort for major depression.
The Cochrane Database of Systematic Reviews. doi:10.1002/14651858.CD000448.pub3. 
PMID 18843608.
```

Comment: Hello, Brenton. I've edited the title a bit because as originally stated, the question was too narrow in scope for the board. (The text is still somewhat too narrow, but I think the basics are still on-topic.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first two sources of information about such questions are

- The publisher of the database may have specified how they want to be cited.
  In fact, The Cochrane Collaboration has such guidelines:

- [Cochrane Policy Manual: How to cite our products](http://www.cochrane.org/policy-manual/2211-how-cite-our-products)
- [Cochrane Reviews: How to cite Cochrane Collaboration products](http://www.cochrane.org/cochrane-reviews/citing-our-products)

The APA style guide may have said something already about this data base.
This is also the case:

- [How to Cite Cochrane Reviews in APA Style](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/01/how-to-cite-cochrane-reviews-in-apa-style.html)
  They explain how a journal article style should be used with year as volume and monthly issue:

> Singh, J., Kour, K., & Jayaram Mahesh, B. (2012). Acetylcholinesterase 
>   inhibitors for schizophrenia. Cochrane Database of Systematic 
>   Reviews, 2012(1), 1–101. doi:10.1002/14651858.CD007967.pub2

If these would not have lead to the required information, a more general idea is:
Following the DOI of your example, I end up at a page of the Cochrane library that also has a tab ["Cited by"](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/14651858.CD000448.pub3/citedby). You could have a look there how other people actually cite the report.

If all this had failed, I'd propably have gone for a technical report style citation.